# What does it mean when a buffer's refCnt() is 0 when it is received by the first handler in a pipeline?

Tags: netty

(Background: I am investigating [a problem we encounter in our gRPC support code when we upgrade Netty to version 4.1.70.Final](https://github.com/oracle/helidon/pull/3423#issuecomment-970881558).  grpc-java itself [sees issues trying to upgrade](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/8605) as well.)

The root of the errors I'm seeing appears to be that in certain situations an `SslHandler` which is at the head of the pipeline receives a `ByteBuf` that has already been freed.  The resulting exception contains this:

```
Caused by: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureAccessible(AbstractByteBuf.java:1454)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1383)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1379)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:355)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getUnsignedByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:368)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslUtils.getEncryptedPacketLength(SslUtils.java:280)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1210)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284)
```

When I debug, I can observe that the pipeline contains two elements, and the `SslHandler` is the first one.  It is using an instance of `OpenSslEngine` as its engine, and the `engineType` is `TCNATIVE`, in case it matters.

I have verified to the best of my ability that `release()` is [not called in our codebase where the problem occurs](https://github.com/oracle/helidon/tree/2.4.0/grpc/server/src/main/java/io/helidon/grpc/server).  Even if it were, our stuff is not ahead of the `SslHandler` in the pipeline.

I can say for sure from setting a breakpoint in `SslHandler::decode` that when it is called, further down the stack at [line 166 in version 4.1.70.Final of `AbstractNioByteChannel.java`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/f49c94c83a5b2a2625913f57515c8dc6ab8c2639/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/nio/AbstractNioByteChannel.java#L166), where the `ByteBuf` is sent to the pipeline, it is already freed.  This is surprising to me, as the buffer looks newly-allocated, and nothing above this line calls `release()`.

The same code works fine with Netty 4.1.63.Final at least.

One PR that seems to have hit after 4.1.63.Final in this general area is https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/11156, in case that too is of use.

Finally, I've found that "undoing" [Netty PR 11242](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/11242) lets our tests pass normally, so something in the task dispatching must be responsible, but I can't find it.

I am trying to determine where `release()` is being called, but so far tracking it down through all of the asynchrony is virtually impossible.  Is this a symptom of a different problem, i.e. should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/680

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/11854 will fix it.